# Where does this pandas warning come from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, chained-assignment

I have a DataFrame. To do a statistical conditional test, I split it into two based on a boolean column ('mar'). I want to use the ratio of counts between the two tables to add a column expressing the proportion of true values in the 'mar' column for each combination of the other columns, as seen below.

```
>>> df_nomar
   alc  cig  mar  cnt
1    1    1    0  538
3    1    0    0  456
5    0    1    0   43
7    0    0    0  279

>>> df_mar
   alc  cig  mar  cnt
0    1    1    1  911
2    1    0    1   44
4    0    1    1    3
6    0    0    1    2
>>> df_mar.loc[:, 'prop'] = np.array(df_mar['cnt'])/(np.array(df_mar['cnt']) + np.array(df_nomar['cnt']))
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:296: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:476: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s

>>> df_mar
   alc  cig  mar  cnt      prop
0    1    1    1  911  0.628709
2    1    0    1   44  0.088000
4    0    1    1    3  0.065217
6    0    0    1    2  0.007117
```

I've gone to the [suggested page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) to investigate the warning. When I assign the new column, I am using the form `df_mar.loc[:, 'prop'] = ...`, just as suggested.

So why am I still getting this warning?

Comment: Related: [chained-assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chained-assignment?sort=votes&pageSize=30) tag

Comment: Read this blog for better understanding - https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need if same sizes of both `DataFrame`s [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for align data:

```
a = df_mar['cnt'].reset_index(drop=True)
b = df_nomar['cnt'].reset_index(drop=True)
df_mar['prop'] = (a/(a + b)).values
```

Another solution is convert to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
a = df_mar['cnt'].values
b = df_nomar['cnt'].values
df_mar['prop'] = a / (a + b)

print (df_mar)
   alc  cig  mar  cnt      prop
0    1    1    1  911  0.628709
2    1    0    1   44  0.088000
4    0    1    1    3  0.065217
6    0    0    1    2  0.007117
```

---

> Where does this pandas warning come from

It obviosly comes from code above. If filter `DataFrame`s then need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df_nomar = df[df['mar'] == 0].copy()
df_mar = df[df['mar'] == 1].copy()
```

If you modify values in `df` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df_nomar` and `df_mar`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: I converted to an np.array in my code, though not by the same method. The warning still persists using the df[index].values way.

Comment: I try your code and no warning, so I guess problem is in lines of code above.

Comment: Maybe you can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/2901002) or [moderna pandas](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1-intro.html) from [tutorials](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas) (look for header `SettingWithCopy`)